# Wiping Hard Drive after BIOS has been edited?

Tags: desktop-computer, wipe

I salvaged an old tower from a warehouse. It actually works fine and boots up into XP. The only problem is that XP is locked with a password, and I think there is a delay after 5 attempts, so I do not think a Brute Force crack would work.

Moreover, I believe the BIOS has been edited to require a password before booting from CD (the computer appears to be a remnant of an old company, meaning the IT guys locked it down.) So, whenever I try to install Linux or an old XP recovery disk, it goes to what appears to be the BIOS registry and requires a password.

Does anyone know any way I can wipe the hard-drive without actually knowing the password? I want to use this computer for some tinkering work, considering it was free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset your bios. It varies for each motherboard, but sometimes there's a jumper on your motherboard to clear the bios, sometimes just a battery. For the battery, remove it and unplug the power for half an hour. When you turn it bak on, the password *should* be gone

Once you do that, you should be able to either install XP from scratch, or get a password removal tool

Comment: Just a note - you don't actually reset your BIOS - you clear the CMOS where BIOS settings are kept.

Comment: Good point. Still does what he's looking for though :p lol

Comment: Great, did exactly what I needed, I think

Comment: @Berwick Remember to mark as answer then

Answer (score 1):

Put the hard disk into another computer, install Windows/Linux from there.

When they reboot to continue the installation, put the hard disk back and continue from the original computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to reset the password on the current XP installation afterwards [ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) will help.

Comment: It's an offline password editor, so it needs to boot the system off of a disk. It also doesn't solve the BIOS password issue for future use/tinkering

Comment: @Luke: that is why I said "also" and "afterwards", as the instructions to clearing the BIOS password have been already presented. Rings a bell?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that word... Edit the answer and I can remove the -1